# What's the significance of the sector breakdown on the War Map?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've played a bit of multiplayer now and whenever I do, the readiness rating bonus that I receive seems to get applied to every single sector. When I go to my single-player game, these values always seem to be exactly the same.

[image]

> Do the values for these sectors ever change so that they're not all
>   the same?
>
> Assuming it does:
>
> - What causes that to happen?
> - Does the Galactic Readiness become an average of the sector scores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be doing only Unknown maps in multiplayer. You can also play specific maps corresponding to those sectors. You'll get a higher increase in that sector then and a smaller one in all the other sectors.

[image]

The unknown maps have a potential boost of 5% everywhere, the specific maps a potential boost of 10% to that sector and less everywhere else. The actual boost you get depends on your performance on the map.

The global readiness rating is just the average of all the sector ratings.